# Showing all Roslyn code fix suggestions in a solution or a project

Tags: visual-studio-2017, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Visual Studio shows Roslyn code fix suggestions within currently active code editor. E.g. when the cursor is positioned on the piece of code that should be fixed or can be improved, the bulb will show up indicating a possible improvement. Here is an example of such a suggestion for the "Use expression body for constructors" C# 7 feature:

[image: Roslyn code fix suggestion: "Use expression body for constructors"]

Is it possible to get all such suggestions for the whole solution at once. Something similar to the [ReSharper's  `Inspect -> Code Issues in Solution`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Inspecting_Code_in_Specific_Scope.html):

[image: ReSharper Inspection Results]

Basically, a command that will open a result window showing all the Roslyn suggestions from all the registered analyzers for the whole solution.

So far I tried several things but couldn't get what I am looking for. For example, the `Analyze -> Run Code Analysis -> On Solution` gives results, but they do not contain suggestions that are seen in the editors while typing the code (like the "Use expression body for constructors"). I tried turning the Solution Wide Analysis on but that didn't help either.

Is it possible to get the suggestions from all the Roslyn analyzers in a single list, similar to the ReSharper's *Code Issues in Solution*?

Comment: Do you have only one place in solution with such problem?

Comment: @Oxoron Thanks for asking :-) Actually, my concrete motivation for the question is the following. C# 7 comes with new features like the mentioned "Use expression body for constructors". VS shows suggestions in code where these new features could be used, but only while editing the code. I would like to get a list of all the places in the whole solution where a new language features could be used. Up to know I couldn't figure out how to do it with built in suggestions so I actually started developing a tool on my own to accomplish this.

Comment: Still not sure what do you want to achieve, but may be you can just filter standard VS Error List (View -> Error List, Ctrl + W,E).

Just filter by Code, and you'll get a list of places with your feature. Further you can copy-paste it.

Comment: This is a useful tip @Oxoron and actually the first thing I tried. The problem is, the suggestions for potential usages of new language features are neither errors nor warnings. So they do not appear in the Error List. I tried selecting all the available code analysis to eventually get these suggestions in the list of warnings, but it didn't work. Turning on all warnings and looking in the Error List is a good start to get insight into the code "health", but unfortunately does not help in this case. Suggestions for new language features will not be displayed. But thanks for the tip anyway :-)

Comment: Did you try to configure Rule set in References -> Analyzers? Or that's not analyzers?

Comment: Yes I tried that as well. Actually, this was the moment when I posted the question on StackOverflow. Yes, they are analyzers. You can see them in the MS.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features. ("Use expression body for constructors" ID is IDE0021.) I selected them all and set their Action to Warning first and then even to Error. (By default they are Hidden.) Now comes the confusing thing. The "Use auto property" analyzer will indeed occur in the Error List, but only that analyzer!? The others will not be shown in the Error List, although they appear in the editor as shown on the image.

Comment: @Oxoron Thanks a lot for helping :-) It motivates me to dig further and try once again. Maybe I forgot some detail somewhere. I'm also thinking now of posting a separate question - Why some of the analyzers configured as Warning in the References -> Analyzers -> Open Active Rule Set do not appear in the Error List.

Comment: Have you made any progress on this. I'm trying to also get to the specific code suggestions.